# Error al intentar guardar el path de la imagen en la base de datos con Angular y Nodejs/express

Tags: nodejs, angular, express, multer

Estoy intentando guardar los datos de un producto con la url de la img en la base de datos con `Angular` y `Nodejs`.

`Nodejs` muestra el siguiente este error: `[1] (node:7256) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`

Aca en `Nodejs` ,mi `books.controller.ts`

```js
export const createBook = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {
    // recibo los datos (de un form, insomnia rest, etc..)
    const { name, year, id_author, id_category, id_editorial, description, quantity, price, url_image, state} = (req.body);
    console.log(name, year, id_author, id_category, id_editorial, description, quantity, price, url_image, state)
    // el id_book en la db es autonumerico no hace falta
    let book_year = parseInt(year);
    let id_aut = parseInt(id_author);
    let id_cat = parseInt(id_category);
    let id_edi = parseInt(id_editorial);
    let cantidad = parseInt(quantity);
    let precio = parseInt(price); 
    let url_img = (req as any).file.path; //?
    console.log('url imagen en server: ' + url_img)
    // let idBook = parseInt(id_book);
    // insert en PostgreSQL
    // const response: QueryResult = await pool.query('INSERT INTO books (name, year, id_author, id_category, id_editorial, description, quantity, price, url_image, state) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10)', [name, book_year, id_aut, id_cat, id_edi, description, cantidad, precio, url_image, state]);
    const response: QueryResult = await pool.query('INSERT INTO books (name, year, id_author, id_category, id_editorial, description, quantity, price, url_image, state) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10)', [name, book_year, id_aut, id_cat, id_edi, description, cantidad, precio, url_img, state]); // ?
    return res.json({
        message: 'El libro ah sido creado exitosamente!',
        body: {
            books: {
              name
            }
        }
    })  
  }
```

Aca en `Nodejs` mi `books.routes.ts`

```js
import { Router } from 'express'
const router = Router();
import express from 'express'
var multer  = require('multer')
const uuid = require('uuid')
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

const path = require('path');

import { createBook } from '../controllers/books.controller'

// ******************* PARA HACER UPLOAD DE IMAGE ******************* //
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callBack) => {
        //carpeta donde va a guardar las imgs
        callBack(null, 'uploads') 
    },
    filename: (req, file, callBack) => {
        // uuid.v4() guarda la img con id aleatorio, para que no
        // se pisen imagenes en el caso que se suban con el mismo nombre
        callBack(null, uuid.v4() + path.extname(file.originalname).toLocaleLowerCase());
    }    
})

const upload = multer({
    storage,
    dest: 'uploads/',
    //dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/uploads'),
    limits: {fileSize: 2000000}, //max permitido de image, 2 mega byte de peso
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        const fileTypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;   // expresion regular
        // mimetype checkea si el archivo es valido ej img/extension del archivo
        const mimetype = fileTypes.test(file.mimetype);
        // con path.extname checkea si la img tiene la extension .jpeg o .jpg o .gif o .png
        const extname = fileTypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname));
        if(mimetype && extname){
            return cb(null, true);
        }
        else{
            cb("Error: el archivo debe ser una imagen valida");
        }
    }
}).single('file');

app.post('/file', upload, (req, res, next) => {
   
    const file = (req as any).file;
    console.log(file);
    if(!file){
        console.log('No se subió ninguna imagen');
    }
    res.send(file);
    // para mostrar la ruta por console log se puede sacar
    var ruta = (req as any).file.path
    console.log('ruta de imagen: ' + ruta);
  })
// ******************* FIN UPLOAD DE IMAGE ******************* //

router.post('/books', upload, createBook); 


export default router;
```

Aca la funcion en `Angular`, donde le envio los datos del formulario al servidor Nodejs/express

```js
createBook(event: Event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.form.valid)
    {
      if (confirm('¿Esta seguro/a que desea agregar el producto?'))
      {
        // obtengo todos los valores del formulario
        this.book = this.form.value;
        this.book.id_author = parseInt(this.selectedIdAut);
        this.book.id_editorial = parseInt(this.selectedIdEdi);
        this.book.id_category = parseInt(this.selectedIdCat);
        // this.book.url_image = '/uploads/' + this.imageSelected;
        this.book.url_image = '';
        // SUBO IMAGEN ////
        if (this.imageSelected != null){
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('file', this.imageSelected);
          // subo la imagen a nodejs
          this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:4000/file', formData).subscribe(
            (res) => console.log(res),
            (err) => console.log('El servidor no guardó la img, no reconoce el formato: ' + err)
          );
          this.cleanImgPreview(); // hago desaparecer la img preview
        }
       // guardo los datos
        this.bookService.createBook(this.book)
        .subscribe((res) => {
          console.log(res);
        });
        // vuelvo a a traer los libros
        this.bookList$ = this.bookService.getBooksWithAuthorName();
        this.resetForm();
        this.book = {} as Book; // vuelvo a declarar objeto para ponerlo en vacio
        // this.toastr.success('Operación exitosa', 'Producto agregado!');
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo creo que tu error es en el createBook , por que intentas acceder a un parámetro que nunca envias, `let url_img = (req as any).file.path; //?`.

Tu mandas cargar el archivo en una petición, `this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:4000/file', formData)` y nunca esperas a que reciba la respuesta, y en tu otra petición mandas llamar la variable file cuando no contiene nada, es por eso que te genera el error.

Lo que tienes que hacer en tu cliente es primero enviar tu archivo, esperar la respuesta de tu servidor y entonces si enviar tu formulario ya con tu imagen cargada

Te dejo un ejemplo de como lo armaria yo, en este caso lo divido en 3 partes,

1. Función que ya tienes que es la que llena el objeto. y valida la imagen.
2. Carga de Imagen
3. Envió de Formulario

```ts
//Función que ya tienes donde validas el formulario, y el confirm
//LLena el objeto book, y valida si tiene imagen para cargar.
createBook(event: Event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.form.valid) {
        if (confirm('¿Esta seguro/a que desea agregar el producto?')) {
            // obtengo todos los valores del formulario
            this.book = this.form.value;
            this.book.id_author = parseInt(this.selectedIdAut);
            this.book.id_editorial = parseInt(this.selectedIdEdi);
            this.book.id_category = parseInt(this.selectedIdCat);
            // this.book.url_image = '/uploads/' + this.imageSelected;
            this.book.url_image = '';

            if (this.imageSelected != null) {
                // SUBO IMAGEN ////
                uploadImage(); //Si tiene imagen la carga
            } else {
                endCreateBook(); // Si no manda el formulario como va
            }
        }
    }
}
//Carga la imagen y cuando termina, asigna el path a la variable url_image.
// envia el formulario al servidor
uploadImage(){
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.imageSelected);
    // subo la imagen a nodejs
    this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:4000/file', formData).subscribe(
        (res) => {
            // obtengo todos los valores del formulario
            this.book.url_image = res.path;
            endCreateBook();
        },
        (err) => console.log('El servidor no guardó la img, no reconoce el formato: ' + err)
    );
    this.cleanImgPreview(); // hago desaparecer la img preview
}
//Envia el formulario al servidor y espera a la respuesta.
endCreateBook() {
    // guardo los datos
    this.bookService.createBook(this.book)
        .subscribe((res) => {
            // vuelvo a a traer los libros
            this.bookList$ = this.bookService.getBooksWithAuthorName();
            this.resetForm();
            this.book = {} as Book; // vuelvo a declarar objeto para ponerlo en vacio
            // this.toastr.success('Operación exitosa', 'Producto agregado!');
        });
}
```

Otra cosa que note es que nunca esperas una respuesta de tu servidor al enviar tu objeto al servicio, y borras todo, incluido tu formulario, y dado que si se te genera un error en tu servidor, perderías todo, por eso lo modifique hasta que recibas la respuesta.

Comment: Adicional en tu controlador ya no accedas a `let url_img = (req as any).file.path; //?`, si no a la variable que obtienes de tu req.body.

Comment: muchas gracias!, tu código es mas entendible y limpio, pero Angular muestra este error en el componente: POST http://localhost:4000/file 404 (Not Found)

books.component.ts:118 El servidor no guardó la img, no reconoce el formato: [object Object]

Comment: Ese es un error genérico que muestras al regresar un error desde tu servicio al enviar la imagen, `this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:4000/file'`, de ahí coloca un console.log(err);, para que veas cual es el error real de tu servicio.

Comment: al hacer console.log(err) muestra esto:

Comment: HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4000/file", ok: false, …}
error: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta charset="utf-8">↵<title>Error</title>↵</head>↵<body>↵<pre>Cannot POST /file</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵"
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4000/file: 404 Not Found"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
url: "http://localhost:4000/file"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase

Comment: Creo puede ser por que no defines tu ruta en el router y la defines en app, mas bien creo seria asi, `router.route("/file").post(upload, (req, res, next) => {.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253898/use-multer-for-file-uploads-inside-a-express-router

Comment: Gracias eduardo, si, era definir la ruta en el router, sin embargo en la base de datos, la url de la img la guarda asi:

Comment: {"fieldname":"file","originalname":"Capitan America odisea de un heroe.jpg","encoding":"7bit","mimetype":"image/jpeg","destination":"uploads","filename":"fd8a78ec-7a72-4bc7-af57-93aeb81f55e2.jpg","path":"uploads\\fd8a78ec-7a72-4bc7-af57-93aeb81f55e2.jpg","size":47224}

Comment: Mi error, únicamente toma la parte path de tu resultado ```this.book.url_image = res.path;```, de igual manera te corrijo la solución

Comment: Excelente funciona! muchas gracias !!